# Highlighting Arabic Vowels

Tags: java, html, fonts, colors, arabic

Here is my code attempting to highlight Arabic vowels in Java:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FontFormatException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Arabic Test");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button1 = new JButton("");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("");
        Font arabicFont = new Font("Arabic Typesetting", Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 60);

        button1.setText("تَّ");
        button2.setText("<html>ت<font color='red'>َّ</font></html>");
        button1.setFont(arabicFont);
        button2.setFont(arabicFont);
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(button2);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

When I try to use HTML tags to color Arabic vowels, the vowels become misaligned and useless (see the example above). Is there an alternative to highlighting these vowels?

Comment: Can anybody help? I have tried different fonts and to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

If you write "تَّ" as one glyph, it can only have one color. This means you need to separate the basic glyph (ت) from the red colored vowel (َّ ), and position them manually.

As you are using HTML within JAVA, I assume that you can use the full range of CSS style commands. This is an approach in HTML/CSS, hoping that this points you towards a solution:

```
<span>
    <span style="position:absolute;">ت</span>
    <span style="color:red; position:absolute;">َّ</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Unfortunately Java Swing does not support CSS :(

Comment: There should be a way in Swing to achieve the "overlapping" effect which is here achieved by css. Can you put one button label directly over the other?

Comment: That is what I am doing now, but I want to use more than two colors. Finding the correct overlap is proving to be quite difficult.

Comment: How many colors do you actually need, and for which elements of the glyph?

Comment: I am trying to use 4 colors. I wish I could show you a picture :S

Comment: This is also a interesting approach: https://j.hn/coloring-hebrew-vowels-and-accents-in-htmlcss/. Here the diacritics are added on top of each other by using css layers based on z-index (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     <head>
       <style>
         body{
           font-size:2em;
           direction:rtl;}
       </style>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>


     <span>ب&zwj;<span style="color:red;">ٌ</span>&zwj;ا</span>
```